# Defining a variable outside the frequently called function in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do processing in a function with a constant list. Let's say I have this ultra simple example:

```
import time

a = ["krava","trava","ognjen","beelzebub"]
def test():
    b = a
    #b =  ["krava","trava","ognjen","beelzebub"]
    min(b)

t = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    test()
print(time.time() -t)
```

The process takes some 44 seconds when I create the list in the function, but takes 42 seconds when it is defined outside. 
Is it acceptable to define the function outside for such a small gain, and is there a third style option that is preferred and gives an improvement and somehow caches the result?
For example, even if partial could give such improvement I feel it would obscure things even more.

Comment: I'm surprised the speed up is so small - you're not just creating the list outside the function, you're creating it *outside the loop*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be fair, the point was to define it outside the loop, otherwise I would think it made no difference.
But I am willing to be proved wrong, thus asking here :)